# Hot to run Dart Process.run detached?

Tags: dart, process

The flutter have [way](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-process_process/ProcessManager/start.html) to run child process detached. But is it possible to do thoiut Flutter in pure Dart? I did not found such future in [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-io/Process-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `dart:io` has a `Process` class that can do that.